# How to initialize back the original state after fadeTo()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this image will be faded out after button click. How to I enable the image to the original state?

```js
const playGame = () => {
  init(); 

  // logic removed for brevity
  $('#hero').fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
}

const init = () => {
  $('#hero').show();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='hero'>
  <img src="hero.jpg">
</div>

<button onclick="playGame()">Fight!</button>
```

`fadeTo()` works but when I tried with `$('#hero').show();` it  doesn't work. I have removed the logic for brevity.

[image]

Comment: do you want to fadein and fadeout like toggle or can you explain the question little more

Comment: When I click the button, it will run the init method which will 'reset' back all my images. This is what I want.

Comment: try the below answer Is this your expected result. do you want to like Life:3 image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use opacity 1

```js
const playGame = () => {
  init(); 

  // logic removed for brevity
  $('#hero').fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
}

const init = () => {
  $('#hero').fadeTo(2000, 1);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='hero'>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bird.jpg">
</div>

<button onclick="playGame()">Fight!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fadeTo()` modifies the opacity of the element. So, `show()` does not work as it is already showing. Try using `fadeIn()` instead. `fadeIn()` will make the opacity 100%.

Comment: But, the problem with using fadeIn is, it will cause display: none

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeToggle()` to toggle between states. More info [here](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/).